# Sorting a 2D List containing both Strings and Integers, sort by integers asc how do i do? (JAVA)

Tags: java, list, sorting, 2d

```
          theList.add(new 2DList("abc123", 9986));
          theList.add(new 2DList("ads314", 1234));
          theList.add(new 2DList("dal192", 3214));
          theList.add(new 2DList("sam273", 9823));
          theList.add(new 2DList("wor213", 7643));
          theList.add(new 2DList("wos987", 1292));
          theList.add(new 2DList("cat202", 9382));
          theList.add(new 2DList("jga213", 9432));
          theList.add(new 2DList("gog113", 1493));
          theList.add(new 2DList("aba231", 9831));
```

I want to sort the Integers by lowest to highest and by doing so also sort the Strings
and save the sorted array in a new array.

maybe by using collector java compare?
but I don't really know how, I would like to learn.

**What if I want to sort a sequence by String and another by Integer? How do I choose between two values I want to sort by integer and then others by String.**

Comment: What is preventing you from even *attempting* to do so?

Comment: First, sort by integer values.  The sort by the string.   You can ArrayLists.sort with a comparator.

Comment: how, what's the method to only choose the integer values? do i have to add them to a new list and then try to sort them ? @ChengThao

Comment: What is `2DList`??  The name of the class is invalid because it cannot start with a digit!

Comment: Sry, I made it all up. :) @AlexRudenko

Answer (score 0):

```
List<2DList> sortedList = theList.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(2DList::getValue)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to get the values out in separate lists:

```
List<Integer> valueList = theList.stream().map(v -> v.getValue()).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> nameList = theList.stream().map(v -> v.getName()).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Because I don't know the names of your methods, I just guessed.  Replace it with whatever method you have as your getter for your integer value.

Comment: is it possible to merge to lists to 2D in a way?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Look into maps.  If your class only has two values, and you know the values are unique, you can simply place your data into a TreeMap with the appropriate Comparator and it will self sort.

Comment: The code won't compile due to the issues in the OP's class name.

Comment: @AlexRudenko yeah, I created my own Tuple class to simulate what he did.  Not sure how he's getting a class to compile with a leading numbers, that's an illegal naming scheme in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a stable sort algorithm on the numbers, and then on the strings. Here's the sample code.

```
import java.util.*;
class DList{
    DList(String n, int v){ name =n; value=v;}
    String name;
    int value;
    public String toString(){
        return "DList[" + name + ", " + value + "]";
    }
}
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<DList> theList = new ArrayList<>();
          theList.add(new DList("abc123", 9986));
          theList.add(new DList("ads314", 1234));
          theList.add(new DList("dal192", 3214));
          theList.add(new DList("sam273", 9823));
          theList.add(new DList("wor213", 7643));
          theList.add(new DList("wos987", 1292));
          theList.add(new DList("cat202", 9382));
          theList.add(new DList("jga213", 9432));
          theList.add(new DList("gog113", 1493));
          theList.add(new DList("aba231", 9831));
          
          theList.forEach(System.out::println);
          System.out.println("==============");
          theList.sort((e1,e2)->{return e1.value-e2.value;});
          theList.sort((e1,e2)->{return e1.name.compareTo(e2.name);});
          theList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
DList[ads314, 1234]
DList[wos987, 1292]
DList[gog113, 1493]
DList[dal192, 3214]
DList[wor213, 7643]
DList[cat202, 9382]
DList[jga213, 9432]
DList[sam273, 9823]
DList[aba231, 9831]
DList[abc123, 9986]
==============
DList[aba231, 9831]
DList[abc123, 9986]
DList[ads314, 1234]
DList[cat202, 9382]
DList[dal192, 3214]
DList[gog113, 1493]
DList[jga213, 9432]
DList[sam273, 9823]
DList[wor213, 7643]
DList[wos987, 1292]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, allocate a record to hold the string and ints.  A record is an immutable class.  A class could also be used.

```
record Data(String getString, int getValue) {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[%s, %s]", getString, getValue);
    }
}
```

Now create a list of data records.

```
List<Data> theList = new ArrayList<>(List.of(new Data("abc123", 9986),
        new Data("ads314", 1234), new Data("dal192", 3214),
        new Data("sam273", 9823), new Data("wor213", 7643),
        new Data("wos987", 1292), new Data("cat202", 9382),
        new Data("jga213", 9432), new Data("gog113", 1493),
        new Data("aba231", 9831)));
```

And start the sorting process.

- sort the original list
- add to a new list `byString`
- print the sorted strings.
- repeat the process for ints storing in `byValue`

```
theList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Data::getString));
List<Data> byString = new ArrayList<>(theList);
System.out.println("Sorted by String\n");
byString.forEach(System.out::println);

theList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Data::getValue));
List<Data> byValue = new ArrayList<>(theList);
System.out.println("\nSorted by value\n");
byValue.forEach(System.out::println);
```

the above prints

```
Sorted by String

[aba231, 9831]
[abc123, 9986]
[ads314, 1234]
[cat202, 9382]
[dal192, 3214]
[gog113, 1493]
[jga213, 9432]
[sam273, 9823]
[wor213, 7643]
[wos987, 1292]

Sorted by value

[ads314, 1234]
[wos987, 1292]
[gog113, 1493]
[dal192, 3214]
[wor213, 7643]
[cat202, 9382]
[jga213, 9432]
[sam273, 9823]
[aba231, 9831]
[abc123, 9986]
```

Here is another example sorting first by string then by int if the strings are equal.

```
List<Data> newList = new ArrayList<>(
        List.of(new Data("to", 10), new Data("be", 8),
                new Data("or", 12), new Data("not ", 15),
                new Data("to", 9), new Data("be", 4),
                new Data("that", 8), new Data("is", 2),
                new Data("the", 3), new Data("question", 2)));

newList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Data::getString)
        .thenComparing(Data::getValue));

System.out.println("\nSorting by String, then int.\n");
newList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
Sorting by String, then int.

[be, 4]
[be, 8]
[is, 2]
[not , 15]
[or, 12]
[question, 2]
[that, 8]
[the, 3]
[to, 9]
[to, 10]
```

Comment: thanks, but what if i want to sort a sequence  by String and another by Integer? How do i choose between what values i want to sort by integer and which ones by String